# Why does my login screen look broken?

Tags: graphics, login

Occasionally, when I restart my computer and boot ubuntu (I have dual boot with Windows 10), my Ubuntu login screen looks fragmented. I'm using Nvidia graphics driver version 470 (proprietary), and I have secure boot disabled. I can still type in my password (though I can't see what is happening) and it will display my desktop like normal after I login.

**Additional Details**
I can re-create this issue by doing the following:

1. Boot into Windows
2. Suspend Windows (Put to sleep)
3. Resume into Windows
4. Reboot computer
5. Boot into Ubuntu

[image]

Comment: Any additional information on what conditions appear to prompt this would help a great deal.  Intermittent problems are the hardest to solve.  Does this happen on cold starts or only restarts, does it happen in recovery mode, do you have a splash screen on your normal login, etc.?

Comment: You right. I just added some additional details. Essentially, I can re-create the problem if I reboot after hibernating/resuming from Windows.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Movieboy  Status please.

Comment: @Movieboy Status please...

Answer (score 2):

**Disable fast start**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel

**Don't do this if you use hibernation**

- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`

**Check your C: drive**

- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

**Check your Ubuntu partition**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I think this should work for you :)